# List out of index on Apache Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

i have this piece of code on my DAG in airflow

```
datas = []

def append_data_to_list():
    data = 1+1
    datas.append(data)
    print(datas)

def get_data_from_list():
    data = datas[0]
    return data
```

the weird part is if i run the code on normal python, it works as expected, but when i run it on airflow, it keeps giving me

```
Index out of range on data = datas[0]
```

when i checked the DAG on append_data_to_list() i prints the datas, but when i try to access it on get_data_from_list() it keeps giving index out of range error.

where did i went wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are accessing your datas list, index 0 before appending any element to it.
It will be helpful if you reference how you are invoking both functions on your dag.
Is the error thrown by parsing the dag itself or on execution time, in some custom operator, sensor, hook you wrote?

Try declaring datas as global and see if the issue is solved, or for modifying it accept it as an argument on your function and return the updated list

Each function is executed in a different subprocess, that's why you are getting this error.

For it to work see [xComs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms)

```
def append_data_to_list(context):
    data = 1+1
    datas.append(data)
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='data', value=datas)
    print(datas)


def get_data_from_list(context):
    datas =  context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(key="data", task_ids=<YOUR_FIRST_TASKID>)
    data = datas[0]
    return data
```

Comment: im invoking the function using python operator
append_data_to_list >> get_data_from_list
the error happened on execution time

Comment: each function is executed in a different subprocess, that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: ah thankyou, one last question xcom_pull will always pull the latest data right ?

Comment: execution_date defaults to the current run but you can also retrieve data for past dates